# Как выборочно обновлять ячейки таблицы html

Tags: html, php, javascript

есть таблица. необходимо некоторые ячейки оставлять без обновления. как сделать это - только фреймами?
есть таблица

```
    текст| переменная из пхп  |
    ---------------------------
    текст|график              |
    ---------------------------
    текст|текст               |
```

вот мне необходимо обновлять не всю таблицу а а где переменная и где график. а поля с текстом должны быть статичны

Comment: @anunak Ничего не понял. Поподробней объясните.

Comment: Так это вопрос больше по php чем по html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот еще вариант с JQuery.

1. В нужной ячейке создаешь <div id="param1"></div>
2. Далее с помощью JQuery получаешь переменную PHP и присваиваешь значение div.
   Например так:

> ```
> $.get('script.php', {/* тут можно передать php скрипту параметры */},
>   function(tmp) {
>   $("#param1").html(tmp);
>   });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

посмотири в сторону [JQGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) -  там уже все сделано за тебя)